# Accessing a previously updated column in the same query behaves differently with JOINs / multi-table UPDATEs

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, increment

Say I have the two tables `players` and `stats` with the following content:

```sql
mysql> select * from players;
+----+-------+
| id | alive |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
|  2 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

```sql
mysql> select * from stats;
+--------+------+------+-------+
| player | win  | lose | ratio |
+--------+------+------+-------+
|      1 |   12 |   20 |   0.6 |
|      2 |    8 |    1 |     8 |
+--------+------+------+-------+
```

And I want to increment every player's `win`-counter, while also updating their win/lose-ratio. This would look something like this:

```sql
update `stats` set `win` = `win` + 1, `ratio` = `win` / `lose`;
```

Note that the incremented value of `win` is used to calculate the `ratio` (just as mysql's manual states here: [1.8.2.2 UPDATE Differences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-update.html)).

Now, when a JOIN is added to the UPDATE-query to restrict it to only update players where `alive = 1`, this behavior changes:

```sql
update `stats` st
inner join `players` pl
    on ( pl.`id` = st.`player` )
set `win` = `win` + 1, `ratio` = `win` / `lose`
where pl.`alive` = 1;

mysql> select * from stats;
+--------+------+------+-------+
| player | win  | lose | ratio |
+--------+------+------+-------+
|      1 |   12 |   20 |   0.6 |
|      2 |    9 |    1 |     8 |
+--------+------+------+-------+
```

The only solution I've found is to assign the new value of `win` to a temporary variable and use that one when calculating the `ratio` instead:

```sql
update `stats` st
inner join `players` pl
    on ( pl.`id` = st.`player` )
set
    `win` = @tmpWin := ( `win` + 1 ),
    `ratio` = @tmpWin / `lose`
where pl.`alive` = 1;
```

**Why does MySQL behave like that, and is there any more elegant solution to a problem of this kind** (other than creating a view to calculate the ratio on the fly)?

The tables were created as follows:

```sql
create table `players` (
    `id`        INT,
    `alive`     TINYINT,
    primary key (`id`)
);

create table `stats` (
    `player`    INT,
    `win`       INT,
    `lose`      INT,
    `ratio`     FLOAT,
    primary key (`player`)
);
```

I'm using MySQL v5.7.17

Comment: With 5.7.17 you can use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the behavior of the join case that indeed looks weird but the following works as expected:

```
 UPDATE `stats` 
 SET `win` = `win` + 1, `ratio` = `win` / `lose` 
 WHERE player IN (SELECT id FROM players WHERE alive=1);
```